# Delete duplicate rows using certain conditions in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

| sid | cid | arrival | departure | country | state | pid | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab1 | a101 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-04-05 | US | ohio | ly1 | 101@gmail.com | 12345 |
| ab2 | a101 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-04-06 | US | ohio | ly1 | 101@gmail.com | 12345 |
| ab7 | a106 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-04-26 | US | Texas | ly6 | 106@gmail.com | 87468 |
| ab8 | a107 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-04-26 | US | Texas | ly7 | 107@gmail.com | 55555 |
| ab1 | a109 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-04-28 | US | Texas | ly9 | 109@gmail.com | 55555 |

If there are more than 1 row with same cid delete it if departure dates between them are 30 days apart. (Here Cid 101 is present more than 1 so we check departure date here, one day difference therefore we keep the latest departure date)

Comment: SQL Server, PostgreSQL, what is it that you use? Please update your question and remove tags that don't apply to your question.

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag as the question explicitly says "MS SQL Server"

Comment: [What have you research and tried so far?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you want to do with this description: "if departure dates between them are 30 days apart.", and how that relates to the rest of your question.

Comment: Please do not post images, current sample data can be changed (using [edit]) if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the window `lead()` to get the next departure date, then we check date diff if less than 30 days then we remove the record :

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
      lead(stayid) over (partition by cid order by departure) as lead_stayid,
      DATEDIFF(day, departure, lead(departure) over (partition by cid order by departure)) as date_diff
  from mytable
)
delete from mytable
Where stayid in (
                select stayid
                from cte
                where date_diff is not null and date_diff < 30
                );
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yDkTRuIm)